# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in a script not populating data (mysql)

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to build an automated CSV to MYSQL dump which occurs everytime the CSV file in a certain directory is updated.

Once the file is updated, the following line of code is executed in a bash script:

```
mysql -u root -p$MASTER_DB_PASSW < /usr/local/scripts/order.sql
```

The contents of order.sql are as follows:

```
use test;
truncate test.ORDER;
load data infile '/home/test/ORDER.csv' into table test.ORDER fields terminated by ',' 
enclosed by '"' 
lines terminated by '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(order_date);
```

For some reason, when I run order.sql manually in Workbench, it works perfectly... but when I run it on the server, the contents of the csv file do not get dumped.   Any tips/advice?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I had an error in my bash script.  I found this by running:

```
bash -x scriptname
```